# What's the meaning of PD?

Tags: vocabulary, abbreviations

In Korea, they are using "**PD**", denoting a person 'in charge of managing a production as in a TV show or film'([wiktionary.com](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/producer)). But the word for the person seems to be *director*, not producer, [who (producer)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/producer) "supervises and controls the finances, creation, and public presentation of a play, film,"(freedictionary.com) ; "[one (producer)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/director) who produces an artistic production like a CD, a theater production, a film, a TV program and so on (wiktonary.com)."
Their using 'PD' is just Konglish? Or do English users use the word for the meaning?

Comment: I think *director* and *producer* are often rather different for TV and movies.

Comment: My guess would be a Production Director [Job Description of a Production Director](http://education-portal.com/articles/Job_Description_of_a_Production_Director.html).

Comment: No-one in any of my classes in an adult hagwon in Korea could tell me what 'PD' actually stood for.

Comment: @snailplane, yes, I was one of the no-one's But thanks to [a Korean](http://kin.naver.com/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=3&dirId=30104&docId=48131682&qb=cGQg7JW97J6Q&enc=utf8&section=kin&rank=3&search_sort=0&spq=0) and the replier, Damkerng T., I now know it's an abbreviation for 'program director.' They call them 'PD' or ['감독'](http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000004965&q=%EA%B0%90%EB%8F%85) in Korea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember that I've heard this word, PD, often enough in Korean TV shows, and yet I think I've never heard its full name.

However, judging from what I've watched, I think this PD probably is [**"program director"** in radio or television as defined by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_director) (under the Broadcasting section):

> In radio or television, a **program director** or director of programming is the person who develops or selects some or all of the content that will be broadcast. A program director's selections are based upon expertise in the media as well as knowledge of the target demographic. Typically, a program director decides what radio program or TV program will be broadcast and when.

As for films, I think I remember that they use the term "director" in Korea as well, but I could be wrong about this. In any case, I believe that the term "program director" is more applied to broadcasting than to film making.

Comment: Yes, what you say is as is in Korea. I’m a Korean but don’t like to watch TV shows or films from both Korean and foreign ones, I’m not accustomed at the words, ‘PD’ or ‘감독.’ But after having read some sayings on Korean websites, I can tell they’re using the words as you say. So ‘film director and theatre director’ they call ‘감독’(director), ‘TV program director’ ‘PD’.

Answer (score 1):

"PD" in the world of television means Producer/Director, i.e. someone who can fulfil both roles. They are becoming increasingly common.